# Difference between PostgreSQL and PostGIS when working with GEO data

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm debating installing the [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) extension for PostgreSQL. However, upon looking at the types in PostgreSQL itself, it seems to support the basic [`Geometric types`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html), including:

```
8.8.1. Points
8.8.2. Lines
8.8.3. Line Segments
8.8.4. Boxes
8.8.5. Paths
8.8.6. Polygons
8.8.7. Circles
```

What is the use case (ignoring UI considerations) for using PostGIS, and what would that give me that PostgreSQL itself wouldn't give me when working with spatial data?

Comment: Native types are not aware of coordinate systems, and list of supported functions https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-geometry.html is shorter than https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html.

Comment: There's a difference between basic geometric algebra, as it is taught in school, and modeling the environment as vector geometries. That's the difference between those types.